# How to simulate folder structure in the URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website where everythings is kept in the index.html file.
To change the pages, I change the URL with hashtags (#) and when the hashtag changes, I start the JavaScript to animate the change.

But I don't like hashtags in a URL.
How can I achieve a URL like `myexampleurl.com/about` instead of `myexampleurl.com/#about`?

Comment: That's not a hashtag, its a fragment identifier. A hashtag is a search term prefixed with a hash symbol.

Comment: And frankly: Get over disliking fragment identifiers, it is the method designed to reference different parts of the same document in a URL. You could perform some horrible hack with duplicate content on multiple URLs and masses of pushState, but it would be awful.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML-5 there is a new feature called pushstate you can use it to solve it [here](http://html5demos.com/history/third) you can find an example.